# Correctly cache route by dynamic parameter

Tags: routes, 9

I have a route with an optional parameter like:

`/foo/bar/{baz}`

`{baz}` is optional.

When accessing that route by a value for baz, the page contents are correct, but the breadcrumb is incorrect and caches the first one that you visit. This makes the breadcrumb incorrect. These are paths that are accessible in the admin area only.

Is there a way to make the breadcrumb correct?

Edit: is the route cache wrong or the menu cache?

Comment: How is the breadcrumb created, is it automatic, or did you do it custom?

Comment: Automatic. This is a standard Controller and route with menu link(s) (for each path to expose) via yaml file.

Comment: What are the cache contexts on the breadcrumb?

Comment: Not sure yet, I haven't implemented any breadcrumb.

Comment: This is not possible that you haven't implemented any breadcrumb module, contrib or custom. The default is /foo/bar on a route /foo/bar/{baz} and the cache context is `url.path.parent` ignoring intentionally the last part of the path for cache efficiency. So the issue you've described can't happen in Drupal out of the box.

Comment: Let me check. I am stepping in to this project, so its possible someone has done something with breadcrumbs.

Comment: Maybe it's due to this bug ? https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2607920

Comment: Yeah that sounds really close, but aw man: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2607920#comment-14461085  I will try that final patch and see what happens.

Comment: Issue #2607920 is not related. *Breadcrumb render cache not invalidated when entity label changes* -> missing cache tag - *Correctly cache route by dynamic parameter* -> missing cache context

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to implement a custom breadcrumb, then add a cache context for the URL.

How to create a custom breadcrumb: https://www.drupal.org/node/2876622

Cache contexts: https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-contexts

Or, you may be able to work something out with the [Custom Menu Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_menu_breadcrumbs) module.